# Crash in release build

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

The application crashes only in the release version of the appstore. In the test flight version, everything works fine, apparently the error is due to code obfuscation...

**Stacktrace:**

```
Crashed: Thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000000000001
0  libswiftCore.dylib       _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 312
1  libswiftCore.dylib       _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 312
2  qr                       closure #1 in SubscriptionRepository.getPaywall1Subscription() + 1024 (SubscriptionRepository.swift)
3  qr                       thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned SubscriptionUi?, @error @owned Error) + 8 [inlined] (<compiler-generated>)
4  qr                       partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned SubscriptionUi?, @error @owned Error) + 32 (<compiler-generated>)
5  qr                       thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@owned SubscriptionUi?, @error @owned Error)partial apply + 12
6  RxSwift                  MapSink.on(_:) + 436 (Map.swift:43)
7  RxSwift                  protocol witness for ObserverType.on(_:) in conformance MapSink<A, B> + 20 (<compiler-generated>)
8  RxSwift                  Sink.forwardOn(_:) + 112 (Sink.swift:35)
9  RxSwift                  AnonymousObservableSink.on(_:) + 312 (Create.swift)
10 RxSwift                  protocol witness for ObserverType.on(_:) in conformance AnonymousObservableSink<A> + 20 (<compiler-generated>)
11 RxSwift                  partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in AnyObserver.init<A>(_:) + 44 (<compiler-generated>)
12 RxSwift                  AnyObserver.on(_:) + 20 (AnyObserver.swift:37)
13 RxSwift                  closure #1 in closure #1 in static PrimitiveSequenceType<>.create(subscribe:) + 440 (Single.swift:35)
14 qr                       closure #1 in SubscriptionRepository.fetchProductsIfNeeded() + 124 (SubscriptionRepository.swift:97)
15 RxSwift                  closure #1 in static PrimitiveSequenceType<>.create(subscribe:) + 60 [inlined] (<compiler-generated>)
16 RxSwift                  partial apply for closure #1 in static PrimitiveSequenceType<>.create(subscribe:) + 104 (<compiler-generated>)
17 RxSwift                  AnonymousObservableSink.run(_:) + 60 [inlined] (<compiler-generated>)
18 RxSwift                  AnonymousObservable.run<A>(_:cancel:) + 256 (Create.swift:75)
19 RxSwift                  Producer.subscribe<A>(_:) + 284 (Producer.swift:18)
20 RxSwift                  Map.run<A>(_:cancel:) + 276 (Map.swift:75)
21 RxSwift                  closure #1 in Producer.subscribe<A>(_:) + 228 (Producer.swift:26)
22 RxSwift                  CurrentThreadSchedulerQueueKey.instance.unsafeMutableAddressor + 0 [inlined] (CurrentThreadScheduler.swift:18)
23 RxSwift                  static CurrentThreadScheduler.queue.getter + 0 [inlined] (CurrentThreadScheduler.swift:61)
24 RxSwift                  specialized CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule<A>(_:action:) + 168 (CurrentThreadScheduler.swift:101)
25 RxSwift                  Producer.subscribe<A>(_:) + 496 (<compiler-generated>)
26 RxSwift                  protocol witness for ObservableType.subscribe<A>(_:) in conformance Observable<A> + 28 (<compiler-generated>)
27 RxSwift                  closure #1 in SubscribeOnSink.run() + 152 (SubscribeOn.swift:79)
28 RxSwift                  closure #1 in DispatchQueueConfiguration.schedule<A>(_:action:) + 8 [inlined] (DispatchQueueConfiguration.swift:27)
29 RxSwift                  partial apply for closure #1 in DispatchQueueConfiguration.schedule<A>(_:action:) + 120 (<compiler-generated>)
30 RxSwift                  thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>)
31 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
32 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_client_callout + 20
33 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_continuation_pop + 504
34 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 584
35 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
36 libdispatch.dylib        _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
37 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 228
```

**Code:**

```
func getPaywall1Subscription() -> Single<SubscriptionUi?> {
    return fetchProductsIfNeeded()
        .map {
            guard let apphudProduct = self.products["test"] else { fatalError("Can't get test product from storekit") }
            guard let product = apphudProduct.skProduct else { fatalError("Can't get skProduct from apphudProduct") }
            guard let period = product.subscriptionPeriod else { fatalError("Can't get period") }
            guard let price = self.formatPrice(product.price, locale: product.priceLocale, period: period) else { fatalError("Can't get price") }
            
            return SubscriptionUi(product: apphudProduct, sku: product.productIdentifier, priceLocalized: price, items: SubscriptionItem.paywall1Values, freeTitle: nil, buttonTitle: L10n.resume, withButtonClose: false, showRouteOnExit: true, paywall: SubscriptionPaywall.paywall1)
        }
        .subscribe(on: ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
        .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
}

func fetchProductsIfNeeded() -> Single<Void> {
    Single.create { observer in
        if (self.products.isEmpty) {
            Apphud.paywallsDidLoadCallback { paywalls in
                let products = paywalls.map { $0.products }.joined()
                products.forEach { self.products[$0.productId] = $0 }
                observer(.success(Void()))
            }
        } else {
            observer(.success(Void()))
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

I think that it is possible to remove obfuscation but I don’t know how, I still wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Try running subscribe on in serial queue instead of concurrent

Comment: You seem to hit one of the `fatalError()`, but it's hard to tell which one. What are the lines numbers for `getPaywall1Subscription()` code? If you find that crash ini Xcode/Organizer/Crashes, it might tell you which line exactly...

Comment: Using `self` inside the `Single.create` closure is a code smell... having a `guard let` with a fatalError in the closure is a code smell, having a non-pure function in the `map` is a code smell... Touching `self.products` in both the create closure and the map closure is a code smell... There's a lot here that makes me uncomfortable. I'm going to have to see a whole lot more code to figure this one out.